justify-center not working and customize the border
I have the following code where I've four elements inside a table cell:td. My goal is to put all the text at center and customize the border. I want a very thin border of same color but it doesn't look like there is a CSS style for this? I tried using justify-content:center; inside #parent CSS but that didn’t work.


 #parent {
        display: flex;
       
      }
    #heading {
        /* float: left; */
        width: 50%;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-style: ridge;
       
      }   
 
#textValue {
        /* float: right; */
        width: 50%;
        border-style: ridge;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
       
      }
     
 <td class="innerdetail">
                <div id="parent">
                  <div id="heading">555</div>
                  <div id="heading">777</div>
                </div>
                <div id="parent">
                  <div id="textValue">AB</div>
                  <div id="textValue">CD</div>
                </div>
               
              </td>




Are you just looking for text-align: center; ?

Yeah, but upon researching it looks like that's not the preferred way to use - am I wrong? I was wondering why justify-content doesn't work.

justify-content goes on #parent not #textValue

First thing's first... You have invalid HTML.  id values need to be unique.  For the code shown you can correct this by making them class values instead.

justify-content is simply the wrong tool for the job here.  That's for flex containers, and the "textValue" elements are not flex containers.  They're within a flex container, but applying that rule to that container won't do anything useful because its children already take up the full available width.  So centering those children does nothing, as they'd continue to take up the full available width.
To center the text in a block element, use text-align: center; on that element:


.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.heading {
  width: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: ridge;
}   

.textValue {
  width: 50%;
  border-style: ridge;
  text-align: center; /* <--- here */
}
<td class="innerdetail">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="heading">555</div>
    <div class="heading">777</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="textValue">AB</div>
    <div class="textValue">CD</div>
  </div>
</td>




Thanks. any idea how can I make the border a very thin line of same color?

@Tan: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

The only option I've tried so far is the ridge option from here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp and I don't see any other option where I can reduce the size to very thin. The ridge one ( and even the groove one) has some width it seems like.

@Tan: You're looking at the wrong documentation.  MDN is generally a more reliable source.  For example, starting here one can find a general border CSS rule and a starting point for a great many other style rules to apply to element borders.

Do you think using a table inside the <td> would be another way of handling above situation?

@Tan: A nested table is valid HTML (assuming both tables are structured correctly), if that's what you're asking.  All that's shown here is the contents of a single table cell, and those contents appear to be at least intended to be tabular in nature.
